# I need help converting VB.Net Linq to C# Linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I recently switched from VB to C# and have, for the most part, been able to make the transition without too much trouble. Currently I am working on converting a VB.Net program into C# and am having trouble with a couple of code blocks that include Linq.

This is one of the VB.Net lines of code that I am having trouble with:

```
Dim emails = From em In dt Group By email = em(1) Into Emailers = Group
```

I have tried to do the same thing in C# like this:

```
var emails = 
    from em in dt
    group emails = em[1] 
    into Emailers = group;
```

I am getting a compile error on the dt, which says **Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataTable'.'GroupBy' not found.** VS also has issues with the whole into Emailers = group;

I have tried to get this right using examples from my search but have not been able to get it right. How should that be converted?

Comment: It would help if you could say what you were trying to achieve, rather than just what the VB looks like.

Comment: You may find [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) VB.NET to C# converter helpful during your conversion process.

Comment: Sorry Jon. I was trying to group the rows by one column. Samuel thanks for the link. I haven't used that particular one but most of the converters that I have tried don't do Linq very well. Thanks, though, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The query syntax is incorrect
- You're trying to use `DataTable` directly; `DataTable` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` which is why it's failing in C#. (Presumably VB handles `DataTable` specially somehow.)

My VB is rubbish, particularly for LINQ, so I don't understand the query - but it *looks* like you're just trying to group the rows by one column. If that's the case, it's as simple as:

```
var emails = from em in dt.AsEnumerable()
             group em by em[1];
```

Or even:

```
var emails = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(em => em[1]);
```

Make sure you have:

```
using System.Data;
```

in your code, so that it'll pick up `AsEnumerable` from [`DataTableExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.aspx).

Comment: `AsEnumerable` on a DataTable is not required in VB.NET, i think the compiler will do it for you.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Right, whereas it is in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var emails = 
    from em in dt.AsEnumerable()
    group emails = em[1] 
    into Emailers = group;
```